# Some confusion about compensator in Power Electronics

Tags: power-electronics

I meet some problems when designing the compensator parameters for the power electronics circuits. I take the buck circuit as the example.
There is a closed loop buck converter. The switch frequncy is 150kHz.
[image]

I use the type Ⅲ compensator using voltage Op-Amp.There are two poles (fp1 and fp2, besides the pole-at-zero fp0) and two zeros (fz1 and fz2) provided by this compensation. The formulas of poles and zeros are as follows:
[image]

[image]

[image]

There are many notes that help design. The application note from Infineon Technologies may help: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-1162.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559a8e17111a

To get the desired cutoff frequency fc and phase margin, all I need to know is the magnitude and phase margin at the fc before compensation. The bode of the buck converter mentioned above is as follows:
[image]

Supposed that I want to set the cutoff frequency to be 10kHz, and the phase margin is 45 degree. Through the bode, I get the magnitude and phase margin at the 10kHz. With the help of formulas of zeros and poles, I can get the cutoff frequency and phase margin that meet my calculation, but when I want to futher increase the cutoff frequency to a certain extent, for example, to 40kHz, the bode that Simplis calculates shows the cutoff frequency instead is far lower than 40kHz. No matter how hard I try, I just can't the cutoff frequency that I want.

There must be something that I don't consider. Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What op-amp did you choose?

Comment: I agree with what Andy wrote: compensating for a low \$f_c\$ with gain can be done with a basic op-amp. If you extend \$f_c\$ to higher frequencies, the op-amp must have an OL response compatible with the response you want otherwise the op-amp imposes its response. Have a look at this [paper](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/1701/articles/H2PToday1701_design_ONSemi.pdf?NOREDIR=1) that I published a while ago. Also, did you look at the automated SIMPLIS [templates](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) on my page?

Comment: Not to mention that a 40 kHz cutoff is too aggressive for a 150 kHz switching frequency.